# $k$ dimensional submanifold and its tangent space

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Is a $k$-dimensional submanifold of dimension $k$? How about its tangent space? Is it of dimension $k$ too? If so, how can I proof them?

The definition of a $k$-dimensional submanifold I am using is as follow:

A set $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is called a $k$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ if for all $x_0 \in M$, there exists an open neighborhood $\Omega$ of $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and a $C^1$-function $f : \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n - k}$ such that
$$M \cap \Omega = f^{-1}(\{0\}) \hspace{10pt} \mbox{and} \hspace{10pt} \mbox{rank } Df(x) = n - k \mbox{ for all } x \in M \cap \Omega.$$

Comment: You might want to look at the implicit function theorem.

Comment: Is this correct? By, implicit function theorem, if $f(x, y) = 0$, we can write $f(x, y) = f(x, g(x)) = 0$, where $x \in \mathbb{R}^{k}$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}^{n - k}$. Thus, the domain of $f$, which is $M$ is of dimension $k$.

Comment: Not the domain of $f$. But $M$ is locally parametrized by $\phi(x) = (x,g(x))$, $x\in U\subset\Bbb R^k$.

Answer (score 0):

A $k$-dimensional submanifold is a set of points in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ that you can locally "flatten-out" to look like what? Like $\mathbb{R}^{k}$. Which has dimension $k$. So in that sense, yes it has dimension $k$.

The tangent space at any point $p$ of the submanifold is a vector space, for which there are $k$ basis vectors. So the tangent space is also of dimension $k$.